# Python 3 JSON serialize class / session?

Tags: json, python-3.x, class, session, jinja2

Error message:

```
Object of type User is not JSON serializable
```

This seems to mean I need to "serialize" the User object but no idea how.

Python 3 code:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, t_email, t_security_level):
        self.t_email = t_email
        self.t_security_level = t_security_level
        
def userClearSession(t_which="user_current"):
    t_email = ""
    t_security_level = ""
    user_instance = User(t_email, t_security_level)
    if t_which == "user_current":
        session["user_current"] = user_instance
    else:
        session["user_edit"] = user_instance
    return
    
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/userRegister', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index(t_title="Login or Register", t_message=""):
    if "user_current" not in session:
        userClearSession(t_which="user_current")
    return render_template(
        "userRegister.html",
        t_title=t_title,
        dict_user_current=session["user_current"]
        )
```

The Flask/Jinja2 HTML template file:

```
[snip]
Email: {{ dict_user_current["t_email"] }}
Security Level: {{ dict_user_current["t_security_level"] }}
[snip]
```

Same error with:

```
[snip]
Email: {{ session["user_current"].t_email }}
Security Level: {{ session["user_current"].t_security_level }}
[snip]
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to store a Python object in a Flask `session`. I'm not familiar with its implementation but the error you get implies that there's a serialisation to JSON somewhere.

Serialising Python objects to JSON is a non-trivial pursuit and unnecessary in this case.

A simpler approach is to store a `User`'s identifier in the `session` and use it to retrieve the `User` object on each request. Replace

```
session["user_current"] = user_instance
```

with

```
session["user_current"] = user_instance.id
```

and redefine your `User` class to fetch the user data from your storage and return it to you. For example,

```py
class User():
    def __init__(email=None, security_level=None):
        self.email = email
        self.security_level = security_level

    def save():
        # logic to store your User's data in your database of choice
        self.id = save_user(self.email, self.security_level)

    def get_from_id(id):
        # logic to retrieve your user's data from your database of choice
        email, security_level = get_user_from_id(id)

        self.id = id
        self.email = email
        self.security_level = security_level

        return self
```

Now, to create an `User` from an `id` in your session you'll call `user_instance = User().get_from_id(session["user_current"])`. Call `current_user.email` to retrieve the email address.

Have a look at [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) if you need session-based authentication.

Comment: Thank you, Simeon! I see the wisdom in what you propose and I'm going to take that route. I'm super new to this kind of coding and wonder if you are up for sharing syntax of how you would change the User class and userClearSession function? I'm sure I could figure it out but if you can share that, it will probably save me hours, heh!

Comment: I added an example `User` class.